# C# Complex Tanh fails for large values

Tags: c#, complex-numbers

This is the implementation from Microsoft for `Sinh` of a `Complex`

```
public static Complex Sinh(Complex value) /* Hyperbolic sin */
{
    double a = value.m_real;
    double b = value.m_imaginary;
    return new Complex(Math.Sinh(a) * Math.Cos(b), Math.Cosh(a) * Math.Sin(b));
}
```

and the implementation for `Cosh`

```
public static Complex Cos(Complex value) {
    double a = value.m_real;
    double b = value.m_imaginary;
    return new Complex(Math.Cos(a) * Math.Cosh(b), - (Math.Sin(a) * Math.Sinh(b)));
}
```

and finally the the implementation for `Tanh`

```
public static Complex Tanh(Complex value) /* Hyperbolic tan */
{
    return (Sinh(value) / Cosh(value));
}
```

Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Numerics/a.html#e62f37ac1d0c67da

I don't understand why Microsoft implented the `Tanh` method that way?

It will fail for very large values. E.g.:

- `tanh(709 + 0i) --> 1`, ok
- `tanh(711 + 0i) --> NaN`, failed should be 1

Any ideas how to improve the `tanh` method that?

For `double` the `Math.Tanh` methods works for large values.

Comment: > "I don't understand why Microsoft implented the Tanh method that way?"
Rumours of Microsoft only employing perfect human beings have no basis in truth!

Comment: Ignoring garbage-in-garbage-out in a math model is not so wise.  NaN is your friend, tells you that the calculation before it produced nonsense.  If you want to ignore it anyway then a basic workaround is if (Math.Abs(value.Real) > 20) value = new Complex(Math.Sign(value.Real), 0);

Comment: @HansPassant. I've no control about the garbage-in. I'm the author of library for uncertainty propagation (METAS UncLib) and one of our customer is using the `tanh` method inside an objective function for non-linear optimization.

Comment: Well, sure you do.  Throw an exception.

Comment: @HansPassant I still think an exception is not a good idea for a math function like `tanh`. It should just return 1 or -1 for large values (real part). MATLAB and even my iPhone behaves like that.

Comment: That is why Tanh() does not throw an exception and favors reporting "garbage in" with NaN.  Your library method should throw it.  And sure, Matlab and phones are for end-users, not programmers.  Keep in mind that I'm trying to convince readers of this question, not you :)

Comment: I still think the `tanh` method should return a valid result for the hole input range of a `double` or `complex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complex `tanh` method could be implemented like that:

```
public static Complex Tanh(Complex value)
{
    double a = value.Real;
    double b = value.Imaginary;
    double tanh_a = Math.Tanh(a);
    double tan_b = Math.Tan(b);
    Complex num = new Complex(tanh_a, tan_b);
    Complex den = new Complex(1, tanh_a * tan_b);
    return num / den;
}
```

This will work as well for large values, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/xGWdQt.

**Update**

As well the complex `tan` method needs to be re-implemented that it works with larges values (imaginary part):

```
public static Complex Tan(Complex value)
{
    double a = value.Real;
    double b = value.Imaginary;
    double tan_a = Math.Tan(a);
    double tanh_b = Math.Tanh(b);
    Complex num = new Complex(tan_a, tanh_b);
    Complex den = new Complex(1, -tan_a * tanh_b);
    return num / den;
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/dh6CSG.

Comment: Is there a drawback of this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment from Hans Passant another way to implement the `tanh` method would be:

```
public static Complex Tanh(Complex value)
{
    if (Math.Abs(value.Real) > 20)
        return new Complex(Math.Sign(value.Real), 0);
    else
        return Complex.Tanh(value);
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/QvUECX.

And the `tan` method:

```
public static Complex Tan(Complex value)
{
    if (Math.Abs(value.Imaginary) > 20)
        return new Complex(0, Math.Sign(value.Imaginary));
    else
        return Complex.Tan(value);
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xzclcu.

Comment: Personally I don't like an if-statement in a math function.

Comment: computer math isn't real math anyway, so this will probably be more performant... less calculations.